# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/futbolextensive/functions.php on line 104

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi i am working on a code to show users of my website posts from the users they are following and the current logged in user's posts too but i get an error like this
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/f....e/functions.php on line 104

```
    //on the home page to display users posts 
    <h4>RECENT ACTIVITY</h4>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">


   <?php
   $users = show_users($_SESSION['login']);
   if (count($users)){
   $myusers = array_keys($users);
   }else{
   $myusers = array();
   }
   $myusers[] = $_SESSION['login'];
   $posts = show_posts($myusers,5);

   if (count($posts)){

   foreach ($posts as $key => $list){
   echo $list['post_date'] ;
   echo $list['user_id'];
   echo $list['post_body'] ;

   }

   }else{
   echo"<p>","<b>","You haven't posted anything yet!","</b>","</p>";
   }
   ?>
   </div>
   </div>

   //the function
   <?php
   function show_posts($user_id,$limit=0){
   global $conn,$user_id;
   $posts = array();
   $user_string = implode(',', $user_id);
   $extra =  " and user_id in ($user_string)";
   if ($limit > 0){
   $extra = "limit $limit";
   }else{
   $extra = '';
   }
   $sql = "select user_id,post_body, post_date from users_posts
   where user_id in ($user_string)
   order by post_date desc $extra";
   echo $sql;
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
   $posts[] = array(  'post_date' => $data->post_date,
   'user_id' => $data->user_id,
   'post_body' => $data->post_body
   );
   }
   return $posts;
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: You need to declare `$myusers` outside the first `if` statement, otherwise it only gets set in the scope of the if and else statements and is lost outside of them.

Comment: `var_dump()` `$myusers` to start with and see what kind of array that gives you.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
$users = show_users($_SESSION['login']);
$myusers = array();
if (count($users)) $myusers = array_keys($users);
```

You need to declare `$myusers` before the `if` statement, otherwise it only gets set in the scope of the `if` and `else` statements and is lost outside of them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to know about **implode()** function. Mainly The **implode()** function returns a string from the elements of an array.

So you must include an array as the second parameter and the separator as first parameter.

```
implode(separator,array)
```

Best solution would be you need to check the **$user_id** variable. If **$user_id** is an array the the implode function should work without error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code

```
$myusers[] = $_SESSION['login'];
```

To

```
$myusers = $_SESSION['login'];
```

Comment: Thanks @manian the session carried the user id so for me to execute the query i had to declare the user id to be entered in the database,